# run python file on k8s

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I have written a simple python file implementing a task with NumPy.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,5, dtype=int)
print(a)
```

Now, I want to run it in k8s.
I wrote the corresponding Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

and then I wrote a yaml file for the deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: np-test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: client-np
      image: <image-name-on-DockerHub>
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

However, the pod is not running and its status is CrashLoopBackOff. I can't figure out why it is not working.

Comment: You may be getting a `CrashLoopBackOff` because the pod exits immediately. You may be able to avoid this by adding a `sleep` to the end of your code, but generally a Pod is meant to implement a long-running process. A [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) is more appropriate for something that you expect to exit.

Comment: For any script pytho, you have to create a `deployment` and `service` who should be responsible to launch your docker image !
I can give you an example in the solution

Comment: @larsks suggestion worked for me and it also makes sense. I added the sleep function and the pod had the status running from the beginning. After the given time passed, the status CrashLoopBackOff returned.

Comment: I will try creating a deployment and a service to test your answer @Aladin and see what's happening, but I guess that the pod will always crash, because it terminates so quickly.

Comment: @Elina_syr Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70745647/in-a-kubernetes-yaml-file-how-do-you-run-a-python-script-first-then-run-the-spe)

Comment: There is no reason to create a Service (because your code doesn't have any network functionality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CrashLoopBackOff tells that a pod crashes right after the start. Kubernetes tries to start pod again, but again pod crashes and this goes in loop.

As @larsks Suggested  You are getting a CrashLoopBackOff because the pod exits immediately. You may be able to avoid this by adding a sleep to the end of your code, but generally a Pod is meant to implement a long-running process. A [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) is more appropriate for something that you expect to exit

A Job creates one or more Pods and will continue to retry execution of the Pods until a specified number of them successfully terminate. As pods successfully complete, the Job tracks the successful completions. When a specified number of successful completions is reached, the task (ie, Job) is complete. Deleting a Job will clean up the Pods it created. Suspending a Job will delete its active Pods until the Job is resumed again.

You can also use a Job to run multiple Pods in parallel.

To fix kubernetes CrashLoopbackoff error refer to this [link](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-crashloopbackoff-kubernetes-error/) .

Comment: That is true. And as I observed, when I executed the pod with the sleep() function in it as @Aladin suggested, it crashed after a while and then in an exponential manner restarted. A Job is more appropriate indeed in this case because at some point, after some restarts, it will be completed.